# Why won't my for loop log out any alt values?

Tags: javascript, html

The goal I'm trying to achieve is to log out the alt values of the blue items when they are clicked on. However, I'm not getting any alt values in the console, and I'm also not getting any error messages.

What do I need to change in order to make this code work?

...........................

```js
const selectShirt = document.getElementById("shirt-select-element");
const defaultShirt = selectShirt.querySelector('option[value="Select a shirt"]');
defaultShirt.hidden = true;

const shirtSelectElement = document.querySelector('#shirt-select-element');
const shirtOptionElements = document.querySelectorAll('#shirt-select-element option');

shirtSelectElement.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    const shirtImg = document.querySelectorAll('.shirt-image');
      
    for (i = 0; i < shirtImg.length; i++) {
      const altTags = shirtImg[i].alt;
      const eventTarget = event.target.value;
      console.log(altTags);
      console.log(eventTarget);
    }

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>

    <form action="index.html" method="post">
      <fieldset class="shirt-selection">
        <legend>Stuff for Sale</legend>  
        
        <ul id="shirt-list">
          <li class="item">
            <a href="#">
              <img class="shirt-image" alt="Yellow shirt">
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="item">
            <a href="#">
              <img class="shirt-image" alt="Blue shirt">
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="item">
            <a href="#">
              <img class="shirt-image" alt="Orange shirt">
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="item">
            <a href="#">
              <img class="shirt-image" alt="Grey shirt">
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        
        <div>
          <label for="shirt-select-element">Shirt Selection:</label>
          <select id="shirt-select-element" name="shirt">
            <option value="Select a shirt">Select a shirt</option>
            <option value="Yellow shirt">Yellow shirt</option>
            <option value="Blue shirt">Blue shirt</option>
            <option value="Orange shirt">Orange shirt</option>
            <option value="Grey shirt">Grey shirt</option>
          </select>
        </div>

      </fieldset>
    </form>
    
    <script src="js.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey droidManInAtux9, did you check my answer? I'd like you to check it and give me feedback. thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, yes this works for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change this line. Then it works.

```
 const altTags = shirtImg[i].getAttribute("alt");
```